# Joomla: How to add a right side menu

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

I'm fairly new to Joomla, but I'm an experienced developer with a tendency to dive into the code a bit too quickly.  Before I start doing that this time around, I'd like to know if there is a simple, proper way way to add a right side menu to the default template in Joomla.  I'm using Joomla 2.5.

Bonus points for info on how to access and create menu types.

Comment: You can set right position (it may have different names of position) for menu, it's depends on template which you are using.

Comment: Beez2 is the default template.  If there is a better template, tell me.  I'm all for it.  How do I set the right position?

Comment: There is many free templates for joomla, depends on which design you are need, you can choose template with menu on right side.

Comment: Any specific suggestions?  But the main point is, through the administration system, is there a way of adding a right side menu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK.  I figured out how to do it without any external modules or a drop of code.  These are the steps:

Go to extensions->module manager

Choose one of the menu module types (I choose 'Menu example')

Enable it

Choose position

scroll down, actually second page, choose position-6, which is Beez5 or Beez_20 top right.

Make sure the menu is enabled for all pages that you want it to be.

Save and close.

Simple as that.

Comment: Great. docs.joomla.org has a ton of information for new users about concepts like module and position. Definitely worth reading over some of them if you are new to Joomla.

Answer (score 2):

Before you start, the template would be the first thing I would install. If you're looking for free then it's going to be lie choosing a car, there are so many to choose from. If you like editing and styling, then you might want to consider the [Yootheme Master Theme](http://www.yootheme.com/themes/downloads/download)

As for the menu on the right hand side, you can create a new module, set the type to **menu** then assign a menu to it. I assume you already know how to create a menu via the Menu Manager ;)

Hope this helps

Comment: +1 for Yootheme recommendation and mentioning how to create new module.

Answer (score 0):

You Can use the plugins for side menu:

http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/structure-a-navigation/menu-systems/sliding-menus/12094

Comment: Looks promising but I'd like concise directions on how to do this without paid for add-ons.  I'd rather modify the code myself then pay for some add-on.